# How to setup one patch with a particular colour in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Why does this work:

```
to setup

 clear-all

 ask n-of 1 patches [set pcolor green]

end
```

But this doesn't:

```
to setup  

  clear-all

  ask patch-at 1 1 [set pcolor green]

end
```

How do you have the patch at 1 1 change colour please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do the following:

```
to setup  
  clear-all
  ask patch 1 1 [set pcolor green]
end
```

Your code is using `patch-at` which reports (ie tells the asking agent) the location or patch coordinates of the patch which is at a certain position (in this case, 1 up and 1 right) from the asker. That is, a relative position. Instead, you are wanting to ask a patch with specific coordinates or absolute position so you use the patch's name such as `patch 1 1`.